# I am using activity indicator in closure one time it work correct for like but not for next

Tags: ios, swift

Kindly help me out for properly start activity indicator when button pressed and stop when process commpleted. My code is given below

startting animation

```
        self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        self.nextButton.enabled = false
        self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        self.newForMe()
        self.finals = self.mids.filter { !self.vmids.contains($0) }
        self.RandomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.finals.count)))


        let accesstoken = self.defaults.valueForKey("accesstoken")
        if self.finals.count != 0
        {

            //self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
            self.like1Button.enabled = true
            self.imgView.hidden = false
            self.vview.hidden = true
            if  self.vc.isConnectedToNetwork() {
                let jSon2 = JSON(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/\(self.finals[self.RandomNumber])?access_token=\(accesstoken!)")!)!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil)

                self.st = jSon2["data"]["images"]["low_resolution"]["url"].stringValue
                self.firstCardString = NSURL(string: self.st)!

                let con = jSon2["data"]["user_has_liked"].boolValue

                if con == true {

                    self.nextPressed(self)
                }

            }else {

               // print("No Connectivity")
            }
            //  print(con)

            let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: self.firstCardString)
            if data != nil
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in



                    self.imgView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                           self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                            })

                    })


            }
            self.nextButton.enabled = true
        }
```

stoping animation
I am astoping it here then also it not starting exectly

```
        else {
            self.like1Button.enabled = false
            self.imgView.image  = UIImage(named: "download (1)")
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No Photo to like", message: "There is no photo to like!!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                //  self.like1Button.hidden = true
                self.imgView.image = nil
               self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()



            }))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
```

Comment: It's hard to say anything concrete. What is the problem exactly? Is indicator not animating or not stop animating?

Comment: Also, you wrapped `self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()` in 2 `dispatch_async`. It's not necessary, after first one you are already on main thread.

Comment: I tried Only one clousure... use

activityindicator.startanimating()

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
//required code... 
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(){
activityIndicator.stopanimating()
}
}